tensorflow to pytorch weight transfer
There is a modified efficientnet TF model, that I'm trying to simulate in pytorch. I have made the architecture changes to the model in pytorch, dumped the TF model weights, and loaded them back in the new pytorch model. The dumping of weights in TF is done using this code:
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
ws = []
for i in range(len(model.variables)):
    ws.append((i, model.variables[i].name, model.variables[i].numpy()))

with open("manually_dumped_contentnet_weights.pkl", "wb") as ofile:
    pickle.dump(ws, ofile)

The weight shapes in pytorch seem to match with the architecture and the imported weights (after trasponsitions needed between conv2d and depth-wise conv2d). I can run the model without any errors. But the output is widely different from the output of the TF model.
I noticed that in the TF code, the model is not loaded directly, but rather in a tf Session:
with Session(graph=Graph(), config=ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=False)) as sess:
    saved_model.loader.load(sess, [saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], model_path)
    patch_feature, patch_label = sess.run(output_nodes,feed_dict={input_node: patch})

Now I'm wondering whether my initial attempt to dump the model weights was not done correctly. Or if I'm missing something else.
The transpositions I have done while loading the data is (3,2,0,1) for conv2d and (2,3,0,1) for depth-wise conv2d:
def reload_conv2d(layer, weights):
    ### weights is a tuple, where each element has consists of a truple: (1) an index number, (2) name of the layer the weights were dumped from in TF, and (3) the weights
    count = 0
    if (
        "/conv2d/kernel" not in weights[0][1]
        and "/conv2d_1/kernel" not in weights[0][1]
        and "depthwise_conv2d/depthwise_kernel" not in weights[0][1]
        and "final_conv2d/final_conv2d" not in weights[0][1]
    ):
        raise ValueError(
            f"need to have conv2d/kernel on the first index but got {weights[0][1]}"
        )
    transpose_shape = (2,3,0,1) if "depthwise" in weights[0][1] else (3, 2, 0, 1)
    transposed_weights = torch.from_numpy(weights[0][2].transpose(transpose_shape[0], transpose_shape[1], transpose_shape[2], transpose_shape[3]))
    layer.weight.data = transposed_weights
    count += 1
    if layer.bias is not None or layer.bias:
        if (
            "/conv2d/bias" not in weights[1][1]
            and "/conv2d_1/bias" not in weights[1][1]
        ):
            raise ValueError(
                f"need to have conv2d/bias on the second index but got {weights[1][1]}"
            )
        layer.bias.data = (
            torch.from_numpy(weights[1][2])
            if type(weights[1][2]) == np.ndarray
            else torch.from_numpy(weights[1][2])
        )
        count += 1
    return layer, count

Why the pytorch and TF models give completely different results on the same input? Is it from the weight dumping, or weight loading... or maybe model architecture change? The fact that input TF weight (after model change and transposition) were loaded fine and I can run the model with no problem doesn't help with debugging it.
